# SO Careers: job listings by recruiters, body shops, etc

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow-jobs

The [House rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) have specific rules for recruiters, middle men, body shops etc:

- Job listings rule #2: "Job listings must be actual job listings."
- Job listings rule #3: "One position and one location per job listing."

Yet I see more and more ads from recruitment companies, about positions that are with their clients and not with the company itself. A few examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/110444/front-end-developer-brunel
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/108848/virtualisatie-specialist-centric
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/106170/alm-engineer-microsoft-ordina
- https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/110806/software-engineers-crafting-solutions-to-pa-consulting

Essentially these are low quality job postings. The type of project and organization where the candidate would be working is obscured by the middle man, Joel scores are absent or fake, and you will see multiple postings of what is essentially the same job.

I've seen this happen to other sites like Monster and LinkedIn, and it's always killed the candidate experience. Will SO careers have the same fate?

Comment: There's a difference between taking on a full-time, permanent role as a consultant or with an agency – knowing it's a consulting job where the clients change from project to project – and being contacted by a recruiter who's looking to fill a job on behalf of a specific company whom they will not disclose to you. If you're not interested in consulting jobs, that's fine, but that doesn't mean other people aren't or that the listings are automatically low-quality.

Comment: I believe it's a very thin line. In the Dutch market, I would say Ordina is on the "consulting" side of the line (actually providing somewhat of a career) and Brunel is on the "recruiter" side of the line (they have a tendency to hire for specific client vacancies and let their employees cross over to the client after a certain time). The problem: these companies are so crelated that it becomes hard to allow one and deny the other. If SO does not draw a clear line, I'm afraid it will be downhill with more and more recruiter posts.

Answer (score 38):

I've read through the comments and given the matter some more thought.

Frankly, I think the SO careers website is not suitable for consultancy / middle man / agency jobs; any jobs where the employer is not the place where the actual project is performed. The site was apparently designed for direct jobs. You have vacancy texts, company profiles, Joel scores etc, which give a reasonably accurate image of the job opening.

In consulting jobs it's a different story. Company descriptions are not as relevant as they do not concern the company, project and product where the candidate will actually be spending his/her time. Joel test scores don't apply. Locations are not accurate. Features like remote working may also not be as they are portrayed (i.e. the consulting company may be fine with it, but its clients can zero that trait with an onsite requirement).

I see three possible outcomes:

1. Block every posting where the work is not at the same company which acts as the employer (the strict option). May not be the most profitable option for SO, but in the end I believe it will be a big plus for the candidates.
2. Allow the current status quo to continue. I think in the long term the lines between proper consulting jobs and plain recruitment agencies will blur too much, causing SO careers to go down the Monsterboard path.
3. The compromise: add a mandatory field to each job opening which indicates if the employer and the development project owner are the same / different entities. Allow users to maintain filters.

Comment: I'm not saying I disagree, but if as you say here, the location isn't accurate because the consulting agency hasn't correctly conveyed whether the client requires onsite travel, then the listing should definitely be regarded as incorrect and probably also as duplicitous. It could just be dealt with the same way as other duplicitous employers.

Comment: Consulting agencies frequently don't know if the client will require travel, or perhaps even where the client will be.  I don't like the idea of excluding consulting agencies (I'd love mine to be able to recruit through SO jobs if they're not already), but I do like the idea of users being able to filter them, +1 for that.

Comment: While I'd love #1, I don't think it's reasonable. The important thing is that each ad be for exactly one job, that the job be real, and that the statements in the ad (location, travel requirements) be accurate. Consultants may have to travel a lot, and there's no way you can know anything about the client organization when taking that kind of job - that's OK, as long as the ad is accurate.

Comment: I think the most realistic option is #3; add fields indicating if the development project is owned by the prospective employer and which amount of the working days would be spent at the client location vs your own compan's location. These fields are objective data, may be moderated by SO members who are familiar with the companies and/or local job market. And they'd make excellent filters for job seekers.

Answer (score 17):

We are having a lively debate about this internally, thanks for bringing it up :) Here's what I think:

1. We have strict rules on *how employers (and their agencies) recruit using our system*. That's what we want to enforce via our house rules.
2. We don't impose rules on *whether a company is a good place to work*. Instead, we want to *inform* the developer so they can make the right choice for them.

One of our big rules for #1 is that you can't hide or obfuscate the job that you'll actually be doing. We're willing to live and die by this one because there's no way a dev can make an informed choice about a job if they don't know who they will end up working for.

Dev agencies tread right on the line, but generally as long as they are the company writing the check and providing some sort of job continuity, they are considered your employer. The job you're applying for is an agency, and as long as you know that going in, that's okay.

What *I* would like to see in this case is (a) to make sure that these companies are being up front about being consulting shops, and (b) to make sure we have tools for developers who *aren't* interested in that to be able to hide them.

Of the 4 jobs listed above, three of them have something related to consulting in their industry "tags" ("Technology Staffing" for one, "IT Consulting" for another, "Consulting" for the 3rd). So even without being able to read the listing, I think they're being reasonably transparent about it. Our problem is that we don't have a way to exclude jobs based on industry tag, and even if we did the tags are inconsistent so it'd be a big pain.

As far as the larger problem you're describing of job boards getting filled up with junk, you're exactly right, but **that's the problem we want to solve**. We believe that there's a right job for everyone, but developer's criteria can vary wildly. We want to have *all the developer jobs in the world* but provide you the tools to immediately **filter that down to the right one for you**. That's why we're putting more and more work into making the homepage of jobs "matches for you" instead of just a list of the most recent jobs.

We're not there yet, but we're on the road. So if you have suggestions for (a) new ways we can get more info from employers up front so you can use that to filter jobs, or (b) new ways that you'd like to filter jobs or be matched to jobs, we're especially open to feature requests on that right now because it's something we're actively looking at.

Comment: On a site note: I was (kinda still am - when I can claw enough time between all the things I love to do) a developer and admin on the Python Software Foundation's Job Board - although, while it's a free listing - we've had discussions about such things in the past. If you wanted to, ping me an email (it's on my profile - permission granted to access my PII), I can give access to the archives and point you to the discussions we've had about things (the problems we've encountered, the issues we've addressed, the concerns raised, and the feature requests etc...). Might give the team a head start.

Answer (score 15):

I'm sorry if you're finding jobs that aren't interesting or relevant to you; however, the fact that you are not personally interested in them doesn't make them illegitimate jobs.

Let's look at the full text of [the rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules) you referred to because the additional details are important:

> **Job listings must be actual job listings.** No career fair invites or recruiter solicitations.

I think it's pretty clear that what this rule is designed to protect against are "DOZENS OF AMAZING, WORLD-CHANGING OPPORTUNITIES AVAILABLE AT THE TOP TECH COMPANIES! SEND ME ALL YOUR INFORMATION AND MAYBE I'LL TELL YOU MORE ABOUT THEM!" types of posts. We're trying to protect against bait-and-switch tactics or bullying where a bad recruiter tries to withhold crucial information from a candidate in order to ensure their own cut for making the introduction.

I don't speak Dutch, so I'm relying on machine translation for some of your examples, but they seem for the most part to be actual jobs at actual companies. There's one that might be borderline (one of the companies seems to position themselves as a recruitment agency themselves, in which case they should be posting more specific jobs that disclose their clients), so if that's the case, flag it and we'll review it more closely.

You say:

> Essentially these are low quality job postings. The type of project and organization where the candidate would be working is obscured by the middle man, Joel scores are absent or fake, and you will see multiple postings of what is essentially the same job.

We can't change the fact that there are "middle men" in the software industry; plenty of companies outsource technical services to third party consultants, and some of them are perfectly lovely places to work. As I mentioned before, there are some companies that are not actually consultants but are just recruiters themselves, and those listings we do need to work on so they contain all the necessary information about the actual clients and projects they're recruiting for.

Lack of a Joel score is not enough of a reason to say that a job listing is low quality, though. Answering the questions on the Joel Test and displaying the score are optional anyway; it's meant as a way for exceptional companies to set themselves apart from the rest. The same way we don't tell employers "hey, this candidate doesn't have any rep on SO, so they're a bad developer", I'm telling you that just because a company doesn't fill out a Joel score, you can't automatically conclude that they're a bad place to work.

Lastly, we don't have specific rules that prevent companies from posting the same job multiple times. It's not the best use of the customer's money because it doesn't really get them more exposure, but it's not *wrong* per se. You can flag duplicate listings and we'll work to educate the customer on why that's not a great idea, but again, it doesn't necessarily mean the job itself is bad. I also do want to point out, though, that "essentially the same job" is a very subjective statement – if you're saying that all jobs at tech consulting firms are the same, then I'm afraid I can't help you. If the skills needed, customers, or consulting firm are different, then they're different jobs.

The next rule...

> **One position and one location per job listing.** Multiple positions need to go into multiple job listings. If you are a recruiting firm posting on behalf of your client, then your client needs to be named as the employer and your role in the process needs to be explained.

Again, I feel like this is really clear. There are plenty of tech consulting jobs where the majority of the work requires you to be in the consulting company's office, in which case that location should be on the job listing. If the consulting work frequently requires the developer to be on the *client's* site, then the job listing should disclose that travel is required.

The key thing, however, is that **a full-time job as a consultant, with a home office that is the primary location of your consulting firm, *is* a "real job".** Is it for everyone? Definitely not. But it's a full-time, salaried position where the consulting firm offers its own work environment, perks & benefits, compensation, career ladder, etc. Temporary contract positions are another animal entirely, and they should be marked as such (and generally are; if they aren't, you can flag the listing for review).

I've worked in an agency (not as a software developer, but working with software developers), and I can tell you firsthand that the "company information" about any agency is absolutely important. Not all agencies are the same; some of them are horrible and some of them are great, if the agent lifestyle is for you. It is definitely not for everyone, but again, it is a legitimate way to conduct business, and one that is not going away anytime soon. Who the client is definitely plays a role in how happy any individual contributor is at a given agency, but honestly, the types of projects you're assigned and whether they work for you is really a conversation that takes place *after* you've signed on with that agency. If the thought of rotating clients around or having to travel really turns you off, nobody is forcing you to apply for agency jobs; the majority of our job listings *are* for companies doing in-house work, so focus on those.

Is there more we at Stack Overflow can do to match you with the most relevant jobs for you? Yeah, absolutely. We introduced match preferences a short time ago, and we can definitely add more dimensions to that. It might be a good idea for us to ask agencies / consultancies to identify themselves as such in a structured way so we can better target those jobs only to developers who are open to that type of work.

We spend an extraordinary amount of time discussing how to best serve developers, so I really do thank you for raising this issue for discussion, and I hope you'll trust that I'm not brushing aside your concerns. But the demand for tech talent takes many forms, and the preferences of developers also take many forms, so there's a lot to consider with every decision we make about what is and isn't allowed on the job board. I think we've come a long way compared to other tech recruiting sites, and I think we can be better still; all I'm asking is for a little trust that we do have the interest of the world's developers in mind but that the world's developers are diverse, and most of the time we're going to have some aspect of the site that's not ideal for one sub-group or other.

Comment: Thanks @Laura for your elaborate answer. It's not about me, I'm happily working contracts and building services without a formal employer. But my point (based on my view on the European and particularly the Dutch labor market) is that the consulting jobs open a slippery slope. They all offer employment in its strict definition (pay checks). Some offer varying projects and an actual career path. Others recruit for specific openings and simply rent their recruits out on an hourly basis, the same job as direct employmeny with the client and subpar salary and benefits.

Comment: The problem: the same job may show up several times through different firms (in various slightly obscured formats). These agencies have significant job ad budgets, so they tend to flush the boards. I know this is a major source of frustration for developers. I think a boolean field (daily work is inside / outside employing company) would fix the candidate experience.

Comment: Ah, okay @FreekWiekmeijer. It wasn't clear to me that you were saying the same jobs were appearing through multiple agencies. Agree that's not a great candidate experience, and we're already talking about whether we can figure out a way to let candidates filter out these types of jobs if they're not interested.

Answer (score -5):

We don't have the man power (and probably won't ever) to review every single listing that goes on the site. This is where we rely on the community to help us out. All you need to do is click "flag a problem" on the right hand side, and we'll look at it ASAP.

Comment: Understandable. However, it does lead to the question: "What checks are made before a job posting is accepted by the careers team?"

Comment: I don't mind putting a little bit of flagging effort in. But where should we put the line? If you would ask a company like Ordina, Brunel or Centric from my examples, each one would claim that the job is really with their organisation. And technically it is: they sign the labor contract and employ the candidate. Then they rent the candidate out on contract jobs to different clients. So these are factually jobs, but still they can never be specific w.r.t. the location, project or organization where the candidate would spend his/her days. Is that in or out of the house rules?

Comment: @JonClements Right now, none. Customers can purchase and post without  any intervention on our part. Having to review every listing would be a huge barrier to entry at the moment.

Comment: @FreekWiekmeijer The litmus test we use internally is who signs the paycheck. For example, a web development shop that does work on behalf of another company, but the employees are paid by the web dev company, the listing does not have to disclose their clients. On the other hand, a recruiting company is free to post on Jobs, as long as they disclose they are recruiters and disclose the client that is hiring.

Comment: That seems to go against Rule 2 of the [house rules](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/house-rules): `Job listings must be actual job listings. No career fair invites or recruiter solicitations. `, though to be fair this is contradicted later with `If you are a recruiter, the client (company) must be divulged.`

Comment: Here's the gray area. These postings pass the litmus test, as the employment is through the posting company. But the actual work (IMHO much more interesting to the candidate than who signs the pay slip) is with an undisclosed, unknown, third party. Hence the posting has nothing concrete on the organization, product, project, team, etc.

Comment: I think a lot of recruiters will post a job listing in hopes of harvesting emails they can market other jobs to. As an anecdote, I got kind of burned by a recruiter-chain that went one level further. Recruiter #1 presented me to a consultancy, who I got an offer from. I eventually realized that I wasn't really working for a consultancy, just one of their projects.

Comment: If you don't have the man power, consider blacklisting the likes of Brunel and Centric. After all, they're essentially competitors in the "matching people and jobs" business. It's just bad business sense to advertise for your competitors, even if they pay you for that.

Comment: I disagree that you don't have the manpower. There are thousands of smart people who check job listings every day. Voting is at the core of SO, I'm sure you can figure out the rest.

Comment: @Juice fyi - further conversation going on here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/325618/how-are-employers-vetted-on-careers