# How are employers vetted on careers?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-jobs

Basically the title states it all, how are employers vetted on the Careers side of stackoverflow?

As I've recently been in contact with a few employers on the careers section. One has stood out to be a winner, whilst having a look on the website for the company looking to hire. No vacancies are offered for the position which I was contacted about. This stands as a little off to me. Maybe I'm wrong, but for peace of mind. How are possible employers vetted for the careers side? Is there any way to check the validity of their employers profile?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they aren't vetted before posting, but you can flag bad ones.

Comment: I was contacted by possible employer in question. Something seems off, I might be overlooking things a slight bit. Might give companies HQ a call to see if this is how they operate with employing for these sort of positions.. but why not on main employers website as a public listing? Am I in the right for thinking that sounds a little off? As I'd hate to flag a valid employer for slight skepticism

Comment: I would be suspect they might be a recruiter agency or something, loads of places just aren't good with website updating though. Usually you can tell if someone is legit by what email address they are using.

Comment: I believe the vetting amounts to "got a credit card?"

Comment: Fwiw, in places I've worked a lot of times we would be working through recruiters rather than post the job ads on our own site; to save us the initial contact and also save us from even more recruiters contacting us.

Comment: Maybe they just don't want a flood of applications, but prefer to choose and contact candidates directly.

Comment: Seems to me that paying real money to post a job ad is about the best and only kind of vetting that's possible, short of sending an SO employee on site to ensure that there is, indeed, an empty office available.

Comment: Have they given you any contact details?  Compare those to the companies ones e.g. email domain or phone number.    If they don't match, then it would be suspicious.  If they ask you for any money for anything, then you know it is a scam.

Comment: It's a tough call.  one thing is, if someone does that, they should be *discrete*.  The guy should just say something like: "Hi, this is Joe at XYZ. Sorry to contact you on your work email. Please contact me about an urgent issue, thanks...."   I feel that's how "using your work email" should be handled, if at all.  If he was very "indiscrete", that is no good.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I have asked in comments on a similar Q&A before on this (I'm not dupe-closing as right now it's possibly more useful to highlight the salient/and related points as they're buried in an answer/comments to something tangential. And well, just have what I personally consider a key point in one place).

The main question was [SO Careers: job listings by recruiters, body shops, etc](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318955/so-careers-job-listings-by-recruiters-body-shops-etc)

Quoting [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/318956) - answered Mar 14 at 14:42 - Juice♦

> We don't have the man power (and probably won't ever) to review every single listing that goes on the site. This is where we rely on the community to help us out. All you need to do is click "flag a problem" on the right hand side, and we'll look at it ASAP.

The two related comments:

> Understandable. However, it does lead to the question: "What checks are made before a job posting is accepted by the careers team?" – Jon Clements♦ Mar 14 at 14:58
>
> @JonClements Right now, none. Customers can purchase and post without any intervention on our part. Having to review every listing would be a huge barrier to entry at the moment. – Juice♦ Mar 14 at 15:15

I'm just a site moderator - this stuff is out of my remit - so I'll leave it to the teams involved to give an official response, but as far as I'm aware, that's the current situation.

Comment: "We don't have the man power" is of course just a business decision. Every listing brings in money, and the price could very well include the cost of vetting the listing. Offloading the vetting to the community for free is possible, of course, but doesn't create a good Careers site. A "barrier to entry" is a _good thing_. This favors quality over quantity, which _does_ make a good Careers site. I don't need 10 bad jobs, I need only one job but it should be a good one.

Comment: For what it's worth when I was looking for a new contract 7 months ago I got ~20 calls a day from various recruiters, most of which were not suitable. I got a grand total of 2 contacts through stack overflow. Both of those were highly suitable. One of them I took the contract and the only reason I didn't go to interview at the second was I'd already decided to accept the first before they got around to giving me a date.